# C++ simple singleton implementation return statement for constructors

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I am trying to implement a simple singleton pattern in C++.

```
#include <iostream>

class simpleSingleton
{
private:
    static simpleSingleton * pInstance;
    simpleSingleton(){}
    simpleSingleton(const simpleSingleton& rs) {
        pInstance = rs.pInstance;
    }
    simpleSingleton& operator = (const simpleSingleton& rs)
    {
        if (this != &rs)
        {
            pInstance = rs.pInstance;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    ~simpleSingleton(){};

public:
    static simpleSingleton& getInstance()
    {
        static simpleSingleton theInstance;
        pInstance = &theInstance;

        return *pInstance;
    }
    void demo()
    {
        std::cout << "simple singleton."
                  << std::endl;
    }
};
simpleSingleton *simpleSingleton::pInstance = nullptr;


int main()
{
    /*Version 1 */
    simpleSingleton * p = &simpleSingleton::getInstance(); // cache instance pointer p->demo();
    p->demo();

    /*Version 2 */
    simpleSingleton::getInstance().demo();

    return 0;
}
```

My question is about the multiple constructors available for `simpleSingleton` class

`simpleSingleton(){}'
'simpleSingleton(const simpleSingleton& rs)`

A constructor is expected to return an object of the class. In the above example neither of the constructors have a return statement. Yet this seems to be standard simpleton implementation. why is that?

Comment: Constructors don't return anything, not explicitly anyways. Singletons use typically (this case included) use a method called 'getInstance' to retrieve the instance of the object. If that is what you're asking?

Comment: You should probably get the basics of c++ classes down before you move on to design patterns like singleton. Also from your code a copy constructor and assignment operator makes no sense for a singleton. It's supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

If you use singleton, use Meyers's singleton :

```
class Singleton
{
private:
    Singleton() = default; // Adapt here
    ~Singleton() = default; // Adapt here
    Singleton(const simpleSingleton& rs) = delete;
    Singleton& operator = (const simpleSingleton&) = delete;
public:
    Singleton& GetInstance()
    {
        static Singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }
};
```

Comment: what does `= delete` and `=default`  mean?

Comment: cppreference.com is your friend, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor